# Number of available threads in threadpool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

In a Threadpool, I have set maximum number of threads.I want number of worker threads are available. i tried.

```
     ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out x, out y);
```

Using this, I got number of available threads (x) which was only decreasing.There was no increase in a number of available threads (x) even after their task was done.
How to get actual number of available threads in thread pool.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? You normally shouldn't have to change those settings.

Comment: *Why* did you set a maximum number of threads? If you are trying to throttle the number of executing threads, this won't help at all. It will only ensure your application hangs under stress. ThreadPools exist so you don't need to manage threads yourself and *don't* cost anything if not used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  in threadpool, i want 5 parallel threads to do some tasks where i have long queue containing number of task. what i want is, whenever any thread of these 5 becomes free, it will dequeue a new task from my task queue. and I am using my separate task queue not threadpools queue because i want to prioritize those tasks. high priority task will get thread directly and low priority will go to end of queue.

Comment: @kaustubh93 - That's no reason to micro-manage the pool. Look at `Parallel.ForEach()`, and maybe at MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5. But try it without that first.

Comment: You don't do that by throttling the entire application's pool. Use an ActionBlock (does almost exactly what you ask) or PLINQ with a DOP limit, or just a ConcurrentQueue with a set number of tasks reading from it. Although, I suspect that just letting .NET do its job will perform better than throttling the number of threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GetAvailableThreads() method does not tell you how many threads there are, it returns how many extra threads still can be created.

From MSDN:

> When GetAvailableThreads returns, the variable specified by workerThreads contains the number of additional worker threads that can be started,

And concerning

> here was no increase in a number of available threads (x) even after their task was done.

How long did you wait? The pool will only slowly destroy idle threads.

Comment: Why limit the number of threads at all? It doesn't limit the number of *executing* threads so it doesn't offer any useful throttling.